# how to fix only first alertbox shows

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, alert

im making a color generator picking game and im not sure why only the first alert for the loop is picked up forever and it ignores all the other ones. i already tried re-writhing it twice and put return after every alert already.

```js
COLOR_ARRAY = ['blue', 'cyan', 'gold', 'gray', 'green', 'magenta', 'orange', 'red', 'white', 'yellow'];

function runGame() {
  let guess = "";
  let correct = false;

  const targetIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * COLOR_ARRAY.length);
  const target = COLOR_ARRAY[targetIndex];
  console.log(targetIndex, target);

  do {
    guess = prompt('I am thinking of one of these colors:\n\n' + COLOR_ARRAY + '\n\n What color am I thinking of ?\n');

    if (guess === null) {
      alert('bye');
      return;
      correct = checkGuess(guess, target);
    }
  } while (!correct);
  alert('congratulations!');
}


function checkGuessing(guess, target) {
  let correct = false;
  let right = true;
  if (COLOR_ARRAY.includes(guess)) {
    alert('Color not recognized.');
  } else if (guess > target) {
    alert('Guess incorrect\n\n higher than target.');
  } else if (guess < target) {
    alert('Guess is incorrect...Lower than target.');
  } else {

  }

  return right;
}

runGame();
```

Comment: Your `checkGuess` is after `return`, so never executed. If removing return statement, it still be executed only when you cancel your `prompt`. Move it outside of `if` body?

Comment: Oh, and there is no function named `checkGuess`, only `checkGuessing`

Comment: You have function checkGuessing and then you call the function checkGuess? And after return, don’t put that checkGuess, because it’s not reachable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is wrong function name `checkGuessing` instead of `checkGuess`
2. `checkGuessing` has wrong logic to check if guess is valid
3. It's only called when user cancels prompt
4. There is no checking if `target == guess`

```js
COLOR_ARRAY = ['blue', 'cyan', 'gold', 'gray', 'green', 'magenta', 'orange', 'red', 'white', 'yellow'];

function runGame() {
  let guess = "";
  let correct = false;

  const targetIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * COLOR_ARRAY.length);
  const target = COLOR_ARRAY[targetIndex];
  console.log(targetIndex, target);

  do {
    guess = prompt('I am thinking of one of these colors:\n\n' + COLOR_ARRAY + '\n\n What color am I thinking of ?\n');

    if (guess === null) {
      alert('bye');
      return;
    }
    
    checkGuess(guess, target);
    
    if (guess == target) {
        correct = true;
    }
  } while (!correct);
  alert('congratulations!');
}


function checkGuess(guess, target) {
  if (!COLOR_ARRAY.includes(guess)) {
    alert('Color not recognized.');
  }
  
  if (guess > target) {
    alert('Guess incorrect\n\n higher than target.');
  }

  if (guess < target) {
    alert('Guess is incorrect...Lower than target.');
  }
}

runGame();
```